# Why I can only post every 3 minutes?

Tags: support, answers, rate-limiting

I wanted to answer to 2 questions and it looks that my answer to the second question is not accepted because I answered the first one less than 3 minutes ago... why is there such a restriction? What is the motivation behind this?

Comment: Because patience is a virtue.

Comment: Many new users may spam answers, whch s hard t clean up.

Comment: I am kind of suffered from the related restriction for 40 mins, if you find my questions good - please consider to help me out of this restriction (vote up?) - https://math.stackexchange.com/users/955245/%d0%9c%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0-marina-s

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The rationale behind this is explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23042/295232) by one of the Community Managers:

> What kind of answers are you posting, if they take less than 3 minutes to write? Take an extra minute or two to provide a link to your sources, or fix spelling.
>
> (As others note, the limit exists to reduce the damage abusive users can - and, prior to the limit *did* - cause the site)

The good news is that you now have more than 125 reputation, so [you're not affected by this anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/295232).